# Telemetry being split

Tags: thingsboard

My device has its own MQTT format which example follows below.

```
 [{"bn": "086BD7FFFE4AD603", "bt": 1620926752}, {"n": "model", "vs": "nit20z"}, {"n": "2803ddec09000020", "u": "Cel", "v": 1.25}, {"n": "gateway", "vs": "086BD7FFFEB97C60"}]
```

I managed to write a transformation script that puts it in a proper way, but the **Rule Chain** splits it the 4 parts and my scripts only works in the message as a whole.

What could be the best way to make the telemetry be processed as a whole in the Rule Chain?
I can not change the device's MQTT format, and don't wanna use an external gateway server.

Comment: Could you define a separate rule chain for this device profile? Then you could remove the rule chain part that breaks your data.

Comment: The problem was my payload is nested, so had to solve it using integrations. Thanks for comment